# Parsing latex with jlatexmath

Tags: java, latex, mathjs

I am using https://github.com/opencollab/jlatexmath to parse latex math formulas in java. When trying to parse a simple complex number:

```
TeXFormula tex = new TeXFormula("32 + 45~i");
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.ParseException: Unknown character : '~' (or 126)
```

The character '~' is supposed to be an unbreakable space as explained in this documentation. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/FAQ#Non-breaking_spaces

The reason of using '~' is because I want to render the latex formula returned by a different library: mathjs.org and it includes the '~' character in some formulas.

Does jlatexmath support '~' or do I have to use a different spacing command?

Comment: I don't know JLaTeXMath, but in math mode in LaTeX spacing is normally done with \, \; \: (see http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_119.html) - Also note, that in math mode spacing is normally NOT done, as the formatter gets it right on its own. Your formula should rather be "32+45i"

Comment: The reason of using "~" it is because I want to render the latex formula returned by a different library: http://mathjs.org/ and it includes the "~" character in some formulas. I fixed it doing:

    latex.replaceAll("~", "\\,")

Before rendering but it is a dirty hack. Do you have a better idea?

Comment: No, sorry. (Apart from using latex.replaceAll("~", " ") because you really should not do spacing in the formula and the normal space will only act as a token delimiter, but not as a visible element)

Comment: Thanks. I will keep the replaceAll.

Comment: How to make 'jlatexmath' with multi lines when latex is long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ~ is now allowed in JLaTeXMath:
https://github.com/opencollab/jlatexmath/commit/27ffa7082efa75e6f86e8788f5cbe2156aa15f5c

Feel free to report bugs.